# debugging magento better way

Tags: product, products

1: there is product detail, a block appears which shows content from /themefile/a.phtml

only when user is online i can see path while enabling developer mode from admin

but when i am not logged in ,i can not see that block and also content of that file /themefile/a.phtml

i am unable to find it where it is defined or written in such large codebase , i looked in theme's catalog.xml but could not find any such refernce to that .

how can i find it , i am stucked from whole day , can any one help me how can i located it ??..

Answer (score 2):

Try

1. If you know the name of the file then do a search of your code base for any file that include this file name.
2. Login to your product admin, then go to that product page layout tab to see if any edit has been made.
3. Take a look at your community and local code pool for any module that may add this functionality.
4. Take a look at your local.xml  for any custom modification.
5. Take a look at your catalog.xml for any custom modification.
6. Enable develop mode and look at what block is using this template file.